# "Z-level" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is an idle question, but neverthless, I think it's interesting.

Does TikZ have a simple way to implement a "z-level" specification. By this, I don't mean 3D drawing, I mean specifying which parts of the picture are on top of what.

So I'd write something like this:

```
\draw[fill, blue,zlevel=1] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[fill,red,zlevel=2] (0,0) circle (1);
```

and have the red circle appear on top of the blue one (since it has a higher z-level). I know I could just reverse the order, but I can imagine that being able to specify things this way round might make incremental changes to a TikZ picture in beamer easier by simplifying the overlay specifications...

I suppose you could do something with `remember picture`, but it seems a "z-level" key would be the easiest solution (from the end user perspective).

Is there anything like this? Is it possible?

Comment: It should be noted that if you need only two levels, then having the part "below" in between ` \begin{scope}[on background layer]…\end{scope}` is enough. The solutions below are to accommodate more than 2 layers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the layers describe in section 113 *Layered Graphics* of the [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=1192).
You need to declare the layers first using `\pgfdeclarelayer` and then
use them with `\pgfsetlayers` outside the picture.
With the `{pgfonlayer}{<layer name>}` environment you can can wrap TikZ or PGF commands to be drawn on this layer. The `background` library provides a `on background layer` style for `scope`s, so it should be possible to define a `zlevel` style as well:

```
\tikzset{zlevel/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={\pgfonlayer{#1}},
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
}}
```

But you need to put all the commands into a `scope`.

Comment: Turns out your last sentence isn't wholly correct!  (See my updated answer)

Comment: @Andrew: Nice! I was thinking about if this might be possible, but didn't had the time to investigate.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Please, I would so use a MWE here now, since I have no idea as how `scope`s work.

Comment: @tohecz: TikZ `scope` are normal environments `\begin{scope}[zlevel=...] ... \end{scope}`.

Comment: Seems like `layers` are very hard to use, for example, I can not draw a line in the background layer.

Answer (score 58):

Yes.  They are called "layers".  I've used this a few times in various solutions:

- [Are boolean operations on TikZ shapes possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11512/are-boolean-operations-on-tikz-shapes-possible/11620#11620)
- [Modified /tikz/double that doesn't go all the way to the end of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18471/modified-tikz-double-that-doesnt-go-all-the-way-to-the-end-of-lines/18479#18479)
- [Drawing a hypergraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/drawing-a-hypergraph/1216#1216)
- [How can I set the background color of the rows and columns of a matrix node in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-of-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-matrix-node-in-ti/14092#14092)

As have various others:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pgfonlayer

**Update:** In a desperate attempt to "out-TikZ" Martin, here's a version that works as a key *on a single path*.  It works by a bit of sneaky hackery together with careful observation as to when particular commands get executed.  We need to install some code at the beginning and the end of the path.  The beginning is okay as TikZ options get parsed early on.  The end is a little trickier and that's where the sneaky hackery comes in.  Basically, the `\tikz@path@do@at@end` macro gets done, as it says, at the end.  It occurs after an `\endgroup` and the keys on the path are examined inside that group, so at first sight it seems that there's no way for a key inside the group to hook in to that `\tikz@path@do@at@end` without making a global assignment (something I'm reluctant to do).  But if we introduce a new `\begingroup` then the original `\endgroup` at the end of the TikZ path-setting routine no longer ends the main grouping but ends our internal grouping, thus allowing us access to `\tikz@path@do@at@end`.  So long as we are careful and end the outer group, followed again by `\tikz@path@do@at@end` (which is now back to its original meaning) then we can put our layer ending code there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \def\tikz@path@do@at@end{\endpgfonlayer\endgroup\tikz@path@do@at@end}%
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!50!white,opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
\draw[ultra thick,red,line width=1cm] (-1,-1) -- (9,9);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\draw[ultra thick,red,line width=1cm,on layer=back] (-1,9) -- (9,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the result that *both* the red lines are behind the green rectangle.

(As with many of my hackery answers, this comes with a "use at own risk" warning, and is also as much about the *hack* as the specific application.  Indeed, I'd been looking for a way to hook in to that `\tikz@path@do@at@end` macro for something else and this might just be how I can do it.)

**Edit:** (again) I don't know how "safe" modifying `\tikz@path@do@at@end` is so here's an alternative that uses `\aftergroup` instead.  It uses the same idea of the hack: start a new group so that the existing `\endgroup` is taken as the end of the inner group.  This is a replacement for the `\pgfkeys` bit in the previous example:

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@node@finish\expandafter{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\endpgfonlayer\tikz@node@finish}%
  }
}
```

**Update:** As Bruce pointed out in the comments, `on layer` doesn't work within the `\node` command (though `\path[on layer=back] node {node};` works).  That's because `\node[options]` becomes `\path node[options]` and not `\path[options] node` so the hooks are in different places.  After a bit of detective work, I found a hook to hang the closing bit of the layer command on.  So `\node[node on layer=back] {on back layer};` works.  I still need to look a bit further to find something that works with `\draw (0,0) -- node[put this on the back layer but not the path] {back} (8,0);`.

(and no longer any need for `\makeatletter`!)

**Update (2012-03-07):** Revisiting this, I found that the `node on layer` was no longer working (if it ever did - I'm dubious now as I don't think that the TikZ code has changed).  I have found a new set of hooks to hook into for the nodes.  One significant advantage of the new approach is that it is possible to put nodes on a different level to their surrounding path.  Rather neat, I thought.

Here's the current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46957/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[tracelevel=silent]{trace-pgfkeys}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfdeclarelayer{front}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \gdef\node@@on@layer{%
      \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\pgfonlayer{#1}\unhbox\tikz@tempbox\endpgfonlayer\egroup}
    \aftergroup\node@on@layer
  },
  /tikz/end node on layer/.code={
    \endpgfonlayer\endgroup\endgroup
  }
}

\def\node@on@layer{\aftergroup\node@@on@layer}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={on layer=back,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={on layer=back,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
\draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5.2cm,xshift=2cm]
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (0,1) -- (0,-1);
\path[on layer=back] node[draw] (a) {At the back of beyond};
\node[node on layer=front] at (0,-2) (b) {At the front of beyond};
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (b.north) -- (b.south);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] node[thin,black,draw,node on layer=back] at (0,-4) (c) {At the side of beyond} (c.north) -- (c.south);
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (0,1) -- (0,-1);
\path node[draw] (a) {At the back of beyond};
\node at (0,-2) (b) {At the front of beyond};
\draw[line width=1cm,red] (b.north) -- (b.south);
\draw[line width=1cm,red] node[thin,black,draw] at (0,-4) (c) {At the side of beyond} (c.north) -- (c.south);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(NB the commented out package is left in deliberately as it was very useful in figuring out what was going on.  See [How do I debug pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34712/86) for more details on that package.)

Here's the result of the above.  In each case, the layering is happening on the left and not on the right.  The fact that the left and right are different proves that something is being shifted from one layer to another.

[image: TikZ inline layers]

Comment: +1 for taking the "out-TikZ Martin" challenge :-) and another impressive lesson for what one can achieve with TikZ by "just" defining some extra styles.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks!  The more I look at the code, the more opportunities I see for doing "weird" stuff like this.  Turns out my last sentence was right: this was just what I needed.  There's lots of unseen "hooks" that one can use to mess with TikZ's routine and make it do something completely different to what was intended.

Comment: @Andrew: This looks brilliant. But your code doesn't seem to work for nodes. If I type \node[on layer=back] {This should be on back layer} at (3,3); then it doesn't put it on the back layer.

Comment: @Bruce: True.  Looking at the code, I can't see any easy hooks for the `\node` command.  Although `\node` is "an abbreviation for `\path node`" the options to the `\node` don't get put on the `\path`.  A way around it is `\path[on layer=back] node {This should be on the back layer} at (3,3);`.

Comment: @Andrew: Ok good, that's not a bad workaround.

Comment: @Bruce: Found some hooks.  See edited answer.

Comment: @Andrew: Any idea if `\path [draw,on layer=A] (0,0) -- (1,1) [on layer=B] (2,2) -- (3,3);` works? I guess not.

Comment: @Martin: probably not because there's only actually one path constructed there and it has to be all on one layer.  (Haven't tested it, but I'd be amazed if it worked.)

Comment: Botheration.  The `node on layer` is no longer working for me.  Must've lost my hooks somewhere.

Comment: @LoopSpace in the last update (2012-03-07) there is a style `end node on layer`, what is the purpose of this style ?

Comment: @Kpym It's been over two years since I last looked at this code so I don't actually remember what that was for.  Most likely, it was part of some code in an older version that I forgot to delete in the last version.

Comment: @LoopSpace thanks. So I don't have to search a deep explanation ;) I'm looking at your code because I'm trying to figure out how to adapt it to solve http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217912/9335 .

Comment: This is really, really neat. (Well, all your TikZ solutions are like that, so saying so maybe be boring. But still.) May I ask how `end node on layer` gets used? I don't really understand the code but only glimpses of it.

Comment: @cfr I really ought to test that code as I suspect (looking at my comment above from Dec 2014) that it isn't actually used, and if I can confirm that then I'll edit this to remove it as it's clearly confusing people! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sorry. I should really read the other comments before adding my own. Otherwise, I would have just tried it and them commented. Apologies.

Comment: @LoopSpace I thought it might be useful to show how to integrate this with the `backgrounds` library. (Actually, also with my own extension of that library which creates a `foreground` to the standard `background`.) If you object even slightly, let me know and I'll delete. Or if you'd rather add the information to your answer, that would obviously be fine too. I removed `end node on layer` and couldn't see any difference. Obviously, your kilometres may vary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately it fails with tikz matrices... any idea what's wrong? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618823/node-on-layer-style-in-tikz-matrix-tikzcd

Answer (score 10):

This is merely a supplement to [Loop Space's fantastic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20426/), which makes it work as I'd expect with the TikZ `backgrounds` library. The only reason I've renamed the background and foreground layers is for consistency with the `backgrounds` library and with my own extension of that.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\makeatletter
% addasu o tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
\tikzset{%
  on foreground layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{foreground}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on foreground layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
  % addasu o ateb Loop Space: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20426/
  %\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46957/86}
  on layer/.code={%
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  node on layer/.code={%
    \gdef\node@@on@layer{%
      \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\pgfonlayer{#1}\unhbox\tikz@tempbox\endpgfonlayer\egroup}
    \aftergroup\node@on@layer
  },
}

\def\node@on@layer{\aftergroup\node@@on@layer}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
  \draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={on layer=background,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
  \draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={on layer=background,line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
    \draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,1) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[ultra thick,white,preaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[line width=1cm,red] (2,-2) -- (2,-4);
    \draw[ultra thick,white,postaction={line width=1cm,blue,draw}] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.2cm,xshift=2cm]
    \draw[line width=1cm,red] (0,1) -- (0,-1);
    \path[on layer=background] node[draw] (a) {At the background of beyond};
    \node[node on layer=foreground] at (0,-2) (b) {At the front of beyond};
    \draw[line width=1cm,red] (b.north) -- (b.south);
    \draw[line width=1cm,red] node[thin,black,draw,node on layer=background] at (0,-4) (c) {At the side of beyond} (c.north) -- (c.south);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
      \draw[line width=1cm,red] (0,1) -- (0,-1);
      \path node[draw] (a) {At the background of beyond};
      \node at (0,-2) (b) {At the front of beyond};
      \draw[line width=1cm,red] (b.north) -- (b.south);
      \draw[line width=1cm,red] node[thin,black,draw] at (0,-4) (c) {At the side of beyond} (c.north) -- (c.south);
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \path (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.north east) \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,.225,.275,.5,.725,.775,1} {coordinate [pos=\i] (p\j)};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill [yellow, fill opacity=.3] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south -| p2) (p7) rectangle (p6 |- current bounding box.south);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[on foreground layer]
    \fill [green, fill opacity=.3] (p2) rectangle (current bounding box.south -| p3) (p6) rectangle (p5 |- current bounding box.south);
  \end{scope}
   \fill [magenta, fill opacity=.3] (p3) rectangle (current bounding box.south -| p4) (p5) rectangle (p4 |- current bounding box.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: layering]