# TikZ: "Inline" pgfonlayer?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Z-level” in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20425/z-level-in-tikz)

When using layers in tikz I usually do the following:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[red] (0,0)--(1,0);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

Is there a way of using the layers inline? e.g.:

```
\draw[layer=background, red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know a way for this. My workaround is creating new commands for layers:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}
    \newcommand{\onlayer}[2]{%
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{#1}%
        #2%
        \end{pgfonlayer}%
    }
    \newcommand{\bglayer}[1]{%
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}%
        #1%
        \end{pgfonlayer}%
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \bglayer{\fill [gray] (1,1) rectangle (3,3);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It’s not as comfortable as your inline version but better (shorter) than using the `pgfonlayer` environment …

**Edit** Another way is shown in ["Z-level" in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20425/z-level-in-tikz)

Comment: Accepted because of "Another way is shown in "Z-level" in TikZ"