# Plot and plane and vector

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to plot a plane and a line vertical on the plane in latex with tikz or pgf for a math assignment.

How do I do that?

Comment: Probably the [tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual is a good place to start. Providing a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is always greatly appreciated. This way people can see what you have already tried and they have something work from. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will! :)

Comment: You could also try looking at [intersection-of-line-and-plane](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104529/tikz-intersection-of-line-and-plane).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some thing like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[plane/.style={trapezium,draw,fill=black!20,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,minimum height=1.5cm},scale=0.7]
\node (p)[plane] at (0,0){.};
\draw (p.center) edge ++(0,2cm) edge[densely dashed] (p.south) (p.south) edge ++(0,-1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]