# Proper syntax for z-levels inside Forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

After reading ["Z-level" in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20425/37570) I tried to implement z-layers in my Forest chart, but unsuccessfully:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{zlevel/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={\pgfonlayer{#1}},
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
}
[Parent,name=Parent
    [SubParent,name=SubParent
        [Child1,name=Child1
            [Child11]
            [Child12,name=Child12]
        ]
        [Child2
            [Child21]
            [Child22,name=Child22,node options={dashed}]
            [Child23,name=Child23]
        ]
        [Child3
            [Child31,name=Child31]
            [Child32]
        ]
    ]
]
%
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, draw=green, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex}}
%
\begin{scope}[zlevel=1]
\draw[->,dashed] (Child22) to (SubParent);
\draw[->,dashed] (Child31) to[out=north east,in=south east] (SubParent);
\end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to draw the dashed arrows behind the forest nodes they are crossing. What changes would be required to achieve that?

Comment: Do you just want `\begin{scope}[on background layer]... \end{scope}`? If you need more layers, you can define them but, as the explanation you linked explains, you have to declare and set them first.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to put stuff in the background is to use the `background` layer rather than defining additional layers. If you need more complex layering, you need to use `\pgfdeclarelayer` and `\pgfsetlayers` as mentioned in the answer you linked to. For the `background` layer, however, this is already done when you load the `backgrounds` library.

To demonstrate the effect, I've added a pale blue fill to your nodes at 75% opacity so that the background lines show through the front layer of the tree:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    fill=blue!25,
    fill opacity=.75,
}
[Parent,name=Parent
    [SubParent,name=SubParent
        [Child1,name=Child1
            [Child11]
            [Child12,name=Child12]
        ]
        [Child2
            [Child21]
            [Child22,name=Child22,node options={dashed}]
            [Child23,name=Child23]
        ]
        [Child3
            [Child31,name=Child31]
            [Child32]
        ]
    ]
]
%
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, draw=green, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex}}
%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[->,dashed] (Child22) to (SubParent);
\draw[->,dashed] (Child31) to[out=north east,in=south east] (SubParent);
\end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree with background connections]

Comment: Oddly enough, I cannot reproduce the semi-transparent fill that works fine in your example. Asked the new question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191107/37570

Comment: @ajeh Is your installation of TeX up to date? Which distribution are you using?

Comment: It's a current MikTex 2.9

Comment: @ajeh I see the other question has shown the issue is not related to an outdated version of `tikz` in any case so hopefully you'll get an answer there after refining your question.

Comment: @ajeh Did this solution answer your (this) question? If so, please consider accepting it so that others can see the question has an answer. (Disclaimer: I will gain points if you do so. Bonus: So will you.)