# Chemfig: How to Make the Boundry of an Atom be Circular?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I am using `\makebox` to control how atoms are printed for consistent results. I would like to print my atoms as a circle instead of a box so that all bonds at all angles will be equidistant from the boundaries of the atom. I noticed that the `\charge` command has an option to print charges along a circular boundary; however, there isn't a similar option for the `\chemfig` command. Is there a command like `\makebox` that produces a circular boundry or would there be another way to accomplish this goal? See the below demonstrations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
%
    \def\foreverunspace{%
      \ifnum\lastnodetype=11
        \unskip\foreverunspace
      \else
        \ifnum\lastnodetype=12
          \unkern\foreverunspace
        \else
          \ifnum\lastnodetype=13
            \unpenalty\foreverunspace
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
%
    \renewcommand{\printatom}[1]{%
        \setbox0=\hbox{#1\foreverunspace}\ifdim\wd0=0pt% if the argument doesn't have a size
            \ensuremath{\mathrm#1}%
        \else%
            \makebox(2.5ex,2.5ex){\ensuremath{\mathrm#1}}% use makebox for atoms
        \fi%
    }%
%
    \setchemfig{%
        % circle=true% not a defined key!
        fixed length=false%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \chemfig{%
        C%
            (-[:0]F)%
            (-[:45]F)%
    }%
%
    \setchemfig{debug=true}%
    \chemfig{%
        C%
            (-[:0]F)%
            (-[:45]F)%
    }%
%
    \hspace{2ex}%
%
    \setchemfig{debug=false}%
    \chemfig{\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,45=\:}{O}}\hspace{2ex}%
%
    \setcharge{debug=true}%
    \chemfig{\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,45=\:}{O}}\hspace{2ex}%
%
    \setcharge{debug=false,circle=true}%
    \chemfig{\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,45=\:}{O}}\hspace{3ex}%
%
    \setcharge{debug=true}%
    \chemfig{\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,45=\:}{O}}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: see the answer at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216353/how-to-annotate-chemfig-drawing-with-circles-and-lines

Comment: @EdsonMarcon That isn't related to my question. I need each atom to take up the space of a circle rather than a circle being drawn around the atom.

Comment: @Jon, do you need graphical elements and outputs different from what the example and your question indicate?  Put it differently, why do you need the package *chemfig*?  Would a straight answer not using the package interest you?

Comment: @DanielN Chemfig has a lot of things set up how I want them (it will save me time), but there are a few things that I wish it had to make it nearly perfect for how I want to use it. If there is another package or a method that would be able to do what I want, I am interested.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I defined two `pic` objects.  One has the border always drawn and is simpler. It is  named `atom` and has two arguments: its name and the list of angles of the small bullets, if any.  The other one, `atom o` depends on three arguments; its third defines the opacity of the  border.  The top element in the figure is given by `atom o`.

So what do you think?  Note that other decorations may be similarly added.

**The code**

```
\tikzset{%
  pics/atom/.style 2 args={%  name, list of angles (charges?)
    code={%
      \path (0, 0)
      node[circle, draw,
      minimum width=6.6ex, minimum height=6.6ex,
      inner sep=1ex, outer sep=1ex,
      text=black] (#1) {$#1$};
      \foreach \i in {#2}{%
        \filldraw[black] (\i: 3.3ex) circle (.25ex);
      }
    }
  },  
  pics/atom o/.style n args={3}{%  name, list of angles, border's opacity
    code={%
      \path (0, 0)
      node[circle, draw, opacity=#3, text opacity=1,
      minimum width=6.6ex, minimum height=6.6ex,
      inner sep=1ex, outer sep=1ex,
      text=black] (#1) {$#1$};
      \foreach \i in {#2}{%
        \filldraw[black] (\i: 3.3ex) circle (.25ex);
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) pic {atom={F}{0, 30}};
  \path (2, 0) pic[red] {atom={He}{90}};
  \path (F) edge[-] (He);

  \path (2, 2) pic[blue] {atom o={O}{80, 110, 180}{.2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's in the spirit of what I am looking for. If I choose to go that route, this should help me get started.