# How can I draw a semi-transparent arrow in TikZ without internal overlap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Drawing a semi-transparent arrow should be easy enough, right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % this doesn't change the result

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-stealth,line width=12pt,opacity=0.5] (0, 0) -- (0, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, this produces the following result:

[image: Result of the above MWE, demonstrating an arrow with overlapping regions in the rectangle and arrowhead]

Note that the arrow is darker than it should be where the rectangle and arrowhead overlap.

How can I get an arrow of this shape and size without this artifact? (Clean solutions preferred.)

Comment: It's a lot easier to stick an arrowhead on the end of a line than combine the two into a single shape.  Hmmm, create an outline then fill it?

Comment: This is what the `transparency group` feature is for: wrap your arrow in `\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5] ... \end{scope}`

Comment: @jake - And after all the work I just did creating a new arrowhead!

Comment: @Jake An answer?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217912/1952

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is what the transparency group feature is for: wrap your arrow in `\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5] ... \end{scope}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=10pt, cyan] (-1,0) -- (1,2);
\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.75]
\draw[-stealth,line width=12pt, red] (0, 0) -- (0, 2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect—thanks very much! For reference, this is on pp. 240–241 of `texdoc tikz`, v2.10.