# Drawing empty, large arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I draw a empty large arrow like this (for example from (0,0) to (2,-2))?

[image]

The only arrow which I am able to draw is the simple vertical/horizontal thin arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[->,line width=1pt, rotate=45] (0,0)-|(2,-2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

like this?

[image]

it is drawn as node shape ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue!30] (0,0) grid[step=1] + (8,-5);
        \node[draw, single arrow,
              minimum height=33mm, minimum width=8mm,
              single arrow head extend=2mm,
              anchor=west, rotate=-60] at (4,-1) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Zarko, yes it is a very good big arrow! Is it possible to specify the inizial and final points (also without grid)? Maybe I can modify only the initial point.

Comment: unfortunately for shapes is not possible to define start and end point (exception are horizontal rectangles by help of `fit` library), but only one. however, in example above is determined west side of shape, and with rotate  its direction. for details see section *67.5 Arrow Shapes* in pgf & tikz manual, page 717.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={single arrow, draw=none, rotate=0}]
    %\draw[step=0.5,very thin,black!20] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \draw[help lines,step=.2] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\draw[help lines,line width=.6pt,step=1] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
 \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-2) {\x};
\foreach \y in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
 \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
    \node [draw=black] {\phantom {hdhdhhhdhdhdh}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Sebastiano. Is it possible to set the start point (x,y) of the arrow?

Comment: Hi, Gennaro, I have add quickly a grid. Do you undestand with the grid the start point of the arrow? Remember that it is not a true arrow, with only line.

Comment: I'd like to set a specific start point as in the Zarko's solution.

Comment: I have to think with all sincerity. Right now I'm in the car and it is difficult to make changes. I can suggest this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217912/style-with-transparency-group

Comment: I have designed a better grid. If you can move the arrow and rotate it, you're done.