# How to set node on line on a different layer than line?

Tags: tikz-styles, pgflayers

Is it possible to declare, that node on lines are on the main layer regardless that lines are in background layer? For example:
[image]

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,%
        backgrounds,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
   \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
        LC/.style = {draw=#1,
            line width=1mm,
            arrows={-Stealth[fill=#1,inset=0pt,length=0pt 1.6,angle'=90]},
            },
         X/.style = {draw, very thin, fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,
            font=\scriptsize,
            text=black, text opacity=1, align=left,
            inner sep=2pt, sloped, anchor=west,pos=0.07},
                        ]\sffamily
%---
\linespread{0.8}
%-------
\coordinate                     (a0)    at (0,0);
\coordinate[right=77mm of a0]   (b0);
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {1,2,...,4}
{
    \coordinate[below=7mm of a\xi]  (a\i);
    \coordinate[below=7mm of b\xi]  (b\i);
}
\draw[|->]  (a0) -- (a3) node[above left]   {$t$};
\draw[|->]  (b0) -- (b3) node[above right]  {$t$};
\draw[LC=gray]  (a1)
    to node[X] {data\\
                $(\text{SeqNum}=0,\ell=1000)$}
                (b2);
%-------
    \begin{scope}[ X/.append style={anchor=east},
                  LC/.append style={transform canvas={yshift=-2mm}},
                  on background layer]
\draw[LC=teal]  (b1)
    to node[X] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)}
                (a2);
   \end{scope}
%----------------
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

The first picture I obtain with drawing second lines twice: first as line and over it again invisible one with node. Since my actual diagrams have up to dozen such lines I looking for more convenient solutions for declaring, that nodes are in main plane even if the line is in background.

Comment: No. If I suppress background layer in the scope, than second line go over the node in the first line. I case, that node in the first line has three rows of text, this is quit disturbing.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, so I deleted my comment; I will also delete this one shortly.

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20426/9335) of Loop Space. In your case, using his code, you can put `\draw[LC=teal]  (b1) to node[yshift=-2mm, node on layer=foreground,X] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)} (a2);`.

Comment: @Kpym, thank you for this link. I need some time to study answer there. On the first sight seem promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's play with boxes.

At some point, TikZ introduces the keys [`behind path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/behind:path) and `in front of path` (to switch back) which basically specifies one or another path box the nodes are placed on. When the path is finally drawn (inside the `;` at the end of paths) these boxes are “used”:

1. the background one (`\tikz@figbox@bg`)
2. the actual path gets drawn
3. the foreground one (`\tikz@figbox`, which is the default one for nodes)

When TikZ finds a node on the path it doesn't actually just *draws* it, it draws the node on one of these two boxes.

These boxes get reset at the start of the path.
These boxes are the reason that nodes are placed on top of their paths (while they are their own paths to begin with).

---

With the [PGF layers](https://tikz.dev/base-layers), something very similar happens but instead of just a node everything between `\begin{pgfonlayer}` and `\end{pgfonlayer}` will be placed inside that box.

At the end of the picture these boxes get “used”. (There is some additional house-keeping which I believe to be for nesting pictures.)

Now, instead of placing the node on the box that gets used by TikZ in the `;` we can *try* to place it directly on one of the layers.

Since this happens somwhere deep in a few groups, this needs to be global (and indeed `\pgfonlayer` does it global as well since that can be used inside a scope somewhere – and indeed it will when you use `on background layer`).

---

To implement this, I swap out one `\setbox` (luckily the first one) for a custom `\tikz@setbox@which` – which is let to `\setbox` so that it works as it usually would – inside the that macro that places the node on that box for the path.

The `node on layer` key just makes it so that `\tikz@setbox@which` does a global `\setbox` and that the box is one of the layers and not one of the path boxes.

Now, you can say

```
\begin{scope}[
  X/.append style={anchor=east},
  LC'/.style={yshift=-2mm}, % no transform canvas
  on background layer]
\draw[LC=teal] ([LC'] b1) % ........ ←
  to node[X, node on layer=foreground] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)} ([LC'] a2);
\end{scope}
```

And this already shows what does not work with this:

- The `main` layer can't be chosen (it's a special one that can't be chosen with `\pgfonlayer` either).
- [`transform canvas`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.4) won't work (but it also doesn't with `behind path`). There may be ways around it but the manual recommends:

  > In short, you should not use canvas transformations unless you really know what you are doing.

  and I'll add *… unless you really need it*.

  I've replaced your addition to `LC` with a normal transformation inside the `LC'` key which is added manually to every coordinate. (I do wish there would be some way to “unfix” coordinates/nodes so that they act as normal coordinates and the transformations would apply to them, too, but even the manual only offers [an @-ridden workaround](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#%5Cpgfpointanchor).)

Additionally don't use it with something else than nodes. The “decider” macro `\tikz@whichbox` is not only used for nodes but also for edges, plot marks, matrices, child nodes (not the same as plain nodes) and pics. Using `\node on layer` there will not work, at best your edges, plot marks, matrix, children and pics simply won't show up. (Because the addition to the box is forgotton after the current path anyway.) More patching has to be done for that.

---

That said, you could also just place an empty node/coordinate along the path (to save the position and the rotation) and then reference that in placing the actual node at the end of all the line drawing. Though, that will need some nice house-keeping to make it easy to use.

And then there's the whole [*Deferred Node Positioning*](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#sec-106.2.3) where you first “do” a node but place it later (used by `forest` and the graph drawing library). That isn't very straight forward either, though. (More boxes!)

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, backgrounds, positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn % replace only first one
\tl_replace_once:Nnn \tikz@fig@continue { \setbox } { \tikz@setbox@which }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\tikz@setbox@which\setbox
\tikzset{node on layer/.code={%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@whichbox\expandafter
    {\csname pgf@layerbox@#1\endcsname}%
  \def\tikz@setbox@which{\global\setbox}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0mm,
  LC/.style = {draw=#1, line width=1mm,
    arrows={-Stealth[fill=#1,inset=0pt,length=0pt 1.6,angle'=90]}},
  X/.style = {draw, very thin, fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,
    font=\scriptsize, text=black, text opacity=1, align=left,
   inner sep=2pt, sloped, anchor=west,pos=0.07}]
\sffamily\linespread{0.8}

\coordinate                     (a0)    at (0,0);
\coordinate[right=77mm of a0]   (b0);
\foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {1,2,...,4}
  \coordinate[below=7mm of a\xi]  (a\i)
   coordinate[below=7mm of b\xi]  (b\i);
\draw[|->] (a0) -- (a3) node[above left]   {$t$};
\draw[|->] (b0) -- (b3) node[above right]  {$t$};
\draw[LC=gray] (a1) to node[X] {data\\$(\text{SeqNum}=0,\ell=1000)$} (b2);

\begin{scope}[
  X/.append style={anchor=east},
  LC'/.style={yshift=-2mm}, % no transform canvas
  on background layer]
\draw[LC=teal] ([LC'] b1)
  to node[X, node on layer=foreground] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)} ([LC'] a2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There are other ways to shift a whole line, see `tikz-cd`'s `shift right` which would be enough here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1 for now). My question is so old, that I need to some time to remember, how I solved this problem and figured out how your proposal works.

Comment: @Zarko I'm not surprised. Maybe it can help others.

Comment: In time of writing my question your answer wouldn't work (doe to used l3syntax). But now it works as I desired. Thank you very much! Unfortunately a quite late, meanwhile I finish my text book, where I draw a bunch of similar diagrams  on a way as I describe in comments to other answer. I will store your solution for possible future projects.

Answer (score 1):

How about placing the node on the front layer with a follow-up path command:

```
\path (b1) to node[X,anchor=east,yshift=-2mm] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)} (a2);
```

Here's the complete document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds,positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    node distance = 0mm,
    LC/.style = {draw=#1,
                 line width=1mm,
                 arrows={-Stealth[fill=#1,inset=0pt,length=0pt 1.6,angle'=90]},
                },
    X/.style = {draw, 
                very thin, 
                fill=white, 
                fill opacity=0.75,
                font=\scriptsize,
                text=black, 
                text opacity=1, 
                align=left,
                inner sep=2pt, 
                sloped, 
                anchor=west,
                pos=0.07},
  ]
 \sffamily
%---
  \linespread{0.8}
%-------
  \coordinate                     (a0)    at (0,0);
  \coordinate[right=77mm of a0]   (b0);
  \foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {1,2,...,4}
    {
      \coordinate[below=7mm of a\xi]  (a\i);
      \coordinate[below=7mm of b\xi]  (b\i);
    } 
  \draw[|->]  (a0) -- (a3) node[above left]   {$t$};
  \draw[|->]  (b0) -- (b3) node[above right]  {$t$};
  \draw[LC=gray]  (a1)
                  to 
                  node[X] {data\\
                  $(\text{SeqNum}=0,\ell=1000)$}
                  (b2);
%-------
  \begin{scope}[X/.append style={anchor=east},
                LC/.append style={transform canvas={yshift=-2mm}},
                on background layer]
    \draw[LC=teal]  (b1)
                    to 
                    (a2);
 \end{scope}
%----------------
  \path (b1) to node[X,anchor=east,yshift=-2mm] {ACK(AckNum$=$1000)} (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the possible solution. As I mentioned in the question, temporary I solve the problem with \draw[draw=none] (a) to node {...} (b);. Your solution with use of path is better. But, in cases of lot such nodes, even using path this approach become cumbersome. So I wonder, if it is possible somehow declare (with tikzset, for example), that all nodes must appear in main layer regardless on which layer they are anchored.

Comment: If you have multiple such paths to create, I would do one of two things: (1) pass them through a `\foreach` group where you can automate the process of drawing within a `scoped` environment and then constructing the node outside that environment.  Or, (2) I would define a macro which would access the parameters to be passed to the `scope`, draw the line within the `scope` environment, and then create the `node` outside the enviornment.

Comment: Ellet, temporary I use \foreach loops for drawing lines on background layer (where it is possible) and nodes separately in in the main layer. This approach has weakness that in such way it is difficult to structure diagram code, maintaining it or reuse it for similar new diagrams. So, the options for node, by which one declare on which layer it should appear, will simplify coding a lot.