# How to remove intersection by overlapping?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want that if a label intersects any of my edges then the label is above the edges.
I am also using Overleaf.
I tried to fill the label white but it does not remove all intersections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary {calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usetikzlibrary {automata,positioning}


\title{Angluin Description with Examples and Illustrations}
\author{Coping Forever}
\date{January 2024}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=2cm,
    every initial by arrow/.style={text=white,->},
    line width=1pt,
    mylabel/.style={font=\bfseries, inner sep=2pt, rectangle, draw=black,fill=white}
]

  \node[state, initial, initial where=right, initial text={}] (s0) at (4.00, 0.00) {$s_0$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s1) at (2.00, 3.46) {$s_1$};
  \node[state] (s2) at (-2.00, 3.46) {$s_2$};
  \node[state] (s3) at (-4.00, 0.00) {$s_3$};
  \node[state] (s4) at (-2.00, -3.46) {$s_4$};
  \node[state] (s5) at (2.00, -3.46) {$s_5$};

  \path[arrows = {-Latex[line width=3pt, length=10pt]}] (s0) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s1);
  \path[->] (s0) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s3);
  \path[->] (s1) edge[loop above] node [mylabel] {0} ();
  \path[->] (s1) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s3);
  \path[->] (s2) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s5);
  \path[->] (s2) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s1);
  \path[->] (s3) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s2);
  \path[->] (s3) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s4);
  \path[->] (s4) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s3);
  \path[->] (s4) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s2);
  \path[->] (s5) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s4);
  \path[->] (s5) edge[loop above] node [mylabel] {1} ();
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: bigboi]

after `fill=white` I got this

[image: bobyboi]

Comment: Welcome. // You could replace some `edge[bend right]` by `to[in= ,out= ]` AND enter suitable in/out angles.  See e.g. here: https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: The simplest fix is just to move `\path[->] (s1) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s3);` to the last line. Then `fill=white` does what you want.

Comment: code compiles now!

Comment: @cfr I want to make lots of automatas like that so a general solution would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_replace_once:Nnn \tikz@fig@continue { \setbox } { \tikz@setbox@which }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\tikz@setbox@which\setbox
\tikzset{node on layer/.code={%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@whichbox\expandafter
    {\csname pgf@layerbox@#1\endcsname}%
  \def\tikz@setbox@which{\global\setbox}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
thick,
mylabel/.style={font=\bfseries, inner sep=2pt, draw, fill=white, node on layer=foreground},
]
\node[state, initial, initial where=right, initial text={}] (s0) at (4.00, 0.00) {$s_0$};
\node[state, accepting] (s1) at (2.00, 3.46) {$s_1$};
\node[state] (s2) at (-2.00, 3.46) {$s_2$};
\node[state] (s3) at (-4.00, 0.00) {$s_3$};
\node[state] (s4) at (-2.00, -3.46) {$s_4$};
\node[state] (s5) at (2.00, -3.46) {$s_5$};

\path[arrows = {-Latex[line width=3pt, length=10pt]}] (s0) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s1);
\path[->] (s0) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s3);
\path[->] (s1) edge[loop above] node [mylabel] {0} ();
\path[->] (s1) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s3);
\path[->] (s2) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s5);
\path[->] (s2) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s1);
\path[->] (s3) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s2);
\path[->] (s3) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s4);
\path[->] (s4) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s3);
\path[->] (s4) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {1} (s2);
\path[->] (s5) edge[bend right] node [mylabel] {0} (s4);
\path[->] (s5) edge[loop above] node [mylabel] {1} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: State graph]

Comment: Code copied from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668356/8650