# TikZ graphs: Specify edge target anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[grow right sep=20,nodes={draw,rectangle}] { a -> {b, long node name} };
\end{document}
```

Which produces this output: [image: MWE output: a -> {b, long node name}]

I'd like to have the edge "a" -> "long node name" to not go from east to north but from south to west. Is this possible while still using just one \graph call? Or do I need to specify that edge manually in an extra command?

(That is, I have basically the same problem as in the question [Edge anchor in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251335/edge-anchor-in-tikz), but I want to use TikZ' graph drawing capabilities instead of manually creating edges.)

Answer (score 5):

To obtain west anchor for node `long node name` you can use `right anchor=west`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[grow right sep=20,nodes={draw,rectangle},right anchor=west] { a -> {b, long node name} };
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The arrows should go from `south` to `west`, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, I think.
[image]

I never used `\graph`. The natural way I do something like what you asked is using `\node`s and `anchor`s, as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {a};
   \node[draw,anchor=west] (b) at ($(a)+(1cm,0)$) {b};
   \node[draw,anchor=west] (c) at ($(a)+(1cm,-1cm)$) {long node name};
   \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
   \draw[->] (a.south) -- (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sure, you have to set a proper distance between the nodes; if not so, the arrow head could intersect the rectangle, but there's no way to avoid this but changing arrow heads. Furthermore, you could use curved arrows.