# Putting node content over a node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgflayers

I use labels to place icons within my TikZ pictures:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  switch/.style={label=center:{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{switch.png}}},
  cloud/.style={label=center:{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{cloud.png}}}
]
  \node[switch] (switch) {};
  \node[cloud, left of=switch] (internet) {Internet};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By default the labels are placed over the node content, so the text "Internet" for instance cannot be seen, because the cloud is being drawn over it.

How can I place either the label underneath the node text, or vice versa the node text above the label?

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20425/z-level-in-tikz/20426#20426). Or you can place "Internet" also as label like this `label=center:{Internet}` after `cloud`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (switch) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-A}};
  \node [label={center:Internet}, left of=switch] (internet){\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-B}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Place the icons inside the node content and the text inside the label. Alternatively, modify the `cloud` node as this:

```
\node[cloud, left of=switch, label=center:Internet] (internet) {};
```

So, the code now becomes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  switch/.style={label=center:{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-A}}},
  cloud/.style={label=center:{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-B}}}
]
  \node[switch] (switch) {};
  \node[cloud, left of=switch, label=center:Internet] (internet) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I use styles, rather than placing the image directly since I am using the elements several times within one picture, but I just figured out by following your example, that a node can have several labels and the labels are placed in order. So that's a way to go.

Comment: Then, use the alternative definition as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your `switch.png` and `cloud.png` images, but here is how to control the label position:

```
\node[cloud, left of=switch,label={[label distance=1cm]90:interent}] (internet) {};
```

You can adjust the distance by changing the `1cm` and the angle by changing the `90`.