# Connecting tree nodes with double arrows a la chef

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw a tree with double arrows. To that end, I have combined the [file system tree](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree) from texample.net with the basic idea of [double arrows a la chef](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/double-arrows):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]

\newcommand{\arrowcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\arrowfillcolor}{white}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  rightarr/.pic={\path[pic actions] (-0.4,0)--(-1,-0.35)--(-1,.35)--cycle;},
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
  edge from parent/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with{\coordinate (0, 0) pic[\arrowcolor,fill=\arrowfillcolor,scale=0.22]{rightarr};},
    },
    draw = \arrowcolor,
    line width = 3pt,
    shorten >= 5.7pt,
    shorten <= 2pt,
    postaction = {decorate},
    postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, white},
  }]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}      
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node [optional] {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}                       
    child [missing] {}                       
    child [missing] {}                       
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This looks like so:

[image]

I don't understand why the vertical arrow lines run straight through at the junctions. Shouldn't the "draw" postaction replay the exact path and draw one inner, 1.4pt wide, white connected surface over the existing path?

Comment: They probably do, but the first `edge from parent` from `texmf` to `doc` is overwritten by the edge from `texmf` to `fonts` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo! Ignasi's comment was eye-opening: "The path" is in fact many paths, each of them starting from top to its respective child. Seems obvious if you think about it. Each of them nicely a la chef, but each of them also ruining the one drawn before. Cool, so here's my next take on the problem, throwing `\pgfonlayer` into the mix, as borrowed from [this post on layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20426/103758):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]

\newcommand{\arrowcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\arrowfillcolor}{white}

\pgfdeclarelayer{front}
\pgfsetlayers{main,front}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/path on layer/.code={
    \def\tikz@path@do@at@end{\endpgfonlayer\endgroup\tikz@path@do@at@end}%
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  rightarr/.pic={\path[pic actions] (-0.4,0)--(-1,-0.35)--(-1,.35)--cycle;},
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
  edge from parent/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with{\coordinate (0, 0) pic[\arrowcolor,fill=\arrowfillcolor,scale=0.22]{rightarr};},
    },
    draw = \arrowcolor,
    line width = 3pt,
    shorten >= 5.7pt,
    shorten <= 2pt,
    postaction = {decorate},
    postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt,white,path on layer=front},
  }]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node [selected] {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node [optional] {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}                      
    child [missing] {}                      
    child [missing] {}                      
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which does the trick for me:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You could just use the `backgrounds` library ....

Comment: @cfr: could you elaborate? I had considered [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20427/103758) method of using the `backgrounds` library, but had no idea of how to put main action and postaction into different scopes. Which (I think) would be necessary.

Comment: I was mainly thinking about the fact that it defines an extra layer and `on layer` etc. out-of-the-box.

Comment: Yes, I know. My problem is that I don't know how those could be possibly applied. According to the pgf manual, `on layer` only works as a `{scope}` option. I have no clue how to squeeze a `{scope}` into the `postaction`

Comment: You may be right about that. You might want to rename the `on layer` style in case you end up wanting to use `backgrounds` for pictures in the same document, in that case and/or just to avoid confusion. But you may well need the different definition. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: You're right, done that.

Comment: Neat! Sorry I can't upvote again ;).