# select tikz layer inside path command

Tags: tikz-pgf, layers

Is it possible to define the tikz-layer to draw on inside a path command, eg `\node[on main layer] at (0,0) {foo};`? It is a bit tedious to put single macros in a scope-environment.

Comment: It doesn't save much but, of course, you could always define `\newcommand\Scope[2][]{\begin{scope}[#1]#2\end{scope}}` and then use constructs like `\Scope{\node at (0,0){foo};}` and `\Scope[rotate=30]{\node at (0,0){foo};}`.

Comment: Which path command do you usually use? That's just a single node

Comment: With `scopes` library you can use `{[on background layer]\node {foo};}`, i.e., `{...}` instead of `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`.

Comment: @ Zarko: Is it simply not possible due to the internal structure or is it not implemented yet?

Comment: @ percusse: Different, but at this moment I am just interested in the `\node` command.

Comment: Recent [`tikz-layers`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-layers) package define some more layers: `behind`, `above` and `glass`.

Comment: @ Ignasi: Yes, but it works only (as far as I can see) on the scope-level, alas.

Comment: @ Ignasi: The `scopes` library seems to be interesting. I will have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20425/z-level-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok, Torbjorn's hint seems to be the right way. It seems to be a complicated so I have to have a closer look. Thanks for the link! --- [four minutes later: works like a charm]

Answer (score 5):

Options `behind path` and `in front of path` allows to superpose nodes and lines that are drawn on the same command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick, draw=green] (0,0) -- 
     node[pos=0.25, behind path, fill=red!30 ]{A} 
     node[pos=0.75, fill=red!30 ]{A} (2,0);

\path (1,1) node[fill=blue!20] {A} 
            node[fill=green, behind path, inner sep=3mm] {A} 
            node[fill=red, inner sep=1mm, in front of path] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's fine and I'll keep it in mind for tasks to come, but I think this does not fit my original question. I need to put something on top of other paths, drawn later.