# Tree: One child node is crossed by line, others not

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the example the fourth child node is crossed by the line, but the others, e. g. the second one not. How can I achieve that also for the fourth one the line is "lying under" the box?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=126mm, textheight=192mm}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=7em,
 every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
 draw, align=center,
 top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]
 \node {Top}
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add an image of the current output, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20426/2388:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=126mm, textheight=192mm}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=7em,
 edge from parent/.style={draw,on layer=back},
 every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
 draw, align=center,
 top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]
 \node {Top}
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} }
 child { node {A\\B\\C\\D} };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]