# How can I draw an "arrow box" with curved arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

Tikz has a special shape called "arrow box". It is a box with arrows going out of it directly.  But how can we change the direction of arrows in this shape? In fact, I need to draw an "arrow box" with curved arrows, something like what is shown in the attached picture.

[image]

Does anyone know how it is possible? By the way, I don't need the other part of this picture. Only the arrow box is my question. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18471/modified-tikz-double-that-doesnt-go-all-the-way-to-the-end-of-lines/18479#18479

Comment: @Ignasi can you clarify how that answer you linked is related to bending arrows?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto You're right, my comment was not clear. The only way I know for drawing *curved empty* arrows is what is suggested in linked answer: a `preaction` which, although serves for straight lines, not always does it for curved ones. Even more, the junction between arrow and box is also difficult. I hope somebody shows us a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is a bit of a hack for the top arrow. Basically any arrow that starts orthogonal to the node's border will have no problem, but diagonal arrows will "break" the make-believe, by appearing like this:

[image: figure 1]

The best way I could think of to deal with this is by automatically adding another node inside which border is white and is positioned on the foreground, thus covering the extra piece.

[image: figure 2]

**Things to improve**:

- This is currently done manually anchoring the node and subtracting the other lengths so that it fits perfectly inside, but I'd like to make it automatic.
- And even better would be to add a "stretchable" path that adapts to the main node (if you add more words for example).
- Also, at this moment, I haven't succeeded in making it work with an `edge` or `to`, but it shouldn't be that hard.

I'll edit the answer if I find a way.

### Output

[image: figure 3]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta, decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfdeclarelayer{fg}
\pgfsetlayers{main,fg}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={draw, line width=.3mm, rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=5cm, fill=white,
        append after command={\pgfextra{\begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}\node[draw=white, line width=1.5mm, minimum height=1.82cm, minimum width=4.82cm, anchor=north west] at ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(\mybor,-\mybor)$) {};\end{pgfonlayer}}}
    },
    warr/.style={draw=black, double=white, line width=1pt, double distance=1mm, shorten >=10.9pt, rounded corners=#1,
        decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{Triangle[open,length=12pt, width=12pt,line width=1.1pt]}}, 
            mark=at position 0 with {\arrow{Turned Square}}},
        preaction={decorate},
        postaction={draw,white, line width=1mm,shorten >=6pt, shorten <=2pt},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (-5,1);
    \coordinate (b) at (-1,-3);

    \node[rect] (na) at (0,0) {This is a very fancy node};

    \draw[warr=2cm] ($(na.south west)!.8!(na.south east)$) |- (b);
    \draw[warr=2cm] ($(na.north west)!.3!(na.north east)+(0,-1mm)$) -- ++(-2cm,2.5cm) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```